# Updating the row with the biggest value

Tags: php, mysql

In the "user_id" column of my table, I'd like to insert the ID of the user who just registred from my page. The idea is to associate his recent generated income with the users id, just to spot an eventual double registration of the income.

In order to do this, I tought to update the user_id column, on the row where income_id has the biggest value, i.e. the last generated income, but something isn't working.  My code is:

```
    $query = "SELECT max( id_income ) FROM `affiliate_income`";
$last_income = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$last = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_income);

        $updtsql = "UPDATE affiliate_income SET `id_user`=".$row_user_code['id_user']."WHERE id_income =".$last;
        $result = mysql_query($updtsql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "something isn't working" ?? What is the error ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id_income =Array' at line 1

Comment: but something isn't working! What and specify if any error is there!

Comment: That means $last  is not string.Its array.So you have to do like this
id_income =".$last['key'];

Comment: Check your variable $last. It may be an array instead of income id

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it in one query,

```
UPDATE  affiliate_income a
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id_income) id_income FROM affiliate_income) b    
           ON a.id_income = b.id_income
SET     a.id_user = 'valueHere'
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to get the max id_income but in the second query (updtsql) you try to find the id_income = array. Besides, you do not put a white space before WHERE clause.

```
$query = "SELECT max( id_income ) AS ii FROM `affiliate_income`";
$last_income = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
$last = mysql_fetch_assoc($last_income);

$updtsql = "UPDATE affiliate_income SET `id_user`=".$row_user_code['id_user']." WHERE id_income =".$last['ii'];
$result = mysql_query($updtsql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: you are right! I have made the changes and now it's working perfectly. thank you, Özkan!

Answer (score 0):

You get the value of `$last` as array.So you have to giv the query like the following

```
$updtsql = "UPDATE affiliate_income SET `id_user`=".$row_user_code['id_user']."WHERE id_income =".$last['id_income'];
```